# How to return the value resolved from promise in function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

File1.ts:
I am calling the below method of file2 service and expecting the response.

```
const output = await this.file2Service.getMainData();
```

File2.ts:
I am expecting the return value(dataSource) from the below method. But what's happening here is "The below function is returning the dataSource even before the code in .then() block gets executed."

So I am getting undefined every time. What needs to be done in order to get the actual dataSource value.

```
public async getMainData(): Promise<any> {
    const data = await this.getSubData();
  data.forEach((result) => {
    result.then((finalResult) => {
            if (finalResult === 'success') {
            const dataSource = await this.callDataSource();
        }
    });
  });
  return dataSource;

}
```

Please ignore the syntax errors in above snippet, Its just an example not the actual code.

Comment: Two problems, the first is mixing up `async`/`await` with the promise `.then` methods, pick one pattern and stick to it.  The second is what are you expecting to return?  From the current attempt it looks like you want to return the last successful result, but there's an array of results, is this what you intend?

Comment: @Matthew yes, I am trying to return the the value present inside the if () block.

Comment: does `this.getSubData()` return an array of promises? another problem is `dataSource`  doesn't exist in the outermost scope of `getMainData`. Need a better picture of the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to invoke `.then` if you're awaiting a method already.

```
public async getMainData(): Promise<any> {
  const data = await this.getSubData();

  for (const result of data) {
    // from your code sample it's unclear 
    // whether getSubData returns a collection of 
    // values or a collection of promises-of-values, 
    // remove the await if you're simply returning values
    
    const finalResult = await result;

    if (finalResult === 'success') {
      return await this.callDataSource();
    }
  }

  throw new Error('could not find a successful result.');
}
```